# Como mandar información a nodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Ok estoy aprendiendo a usar nodeJS y use una API de clima. Ahora del lado del cliente con JS estoy obteniendo la geolocalización del usuario con este codigo.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePosition);
  } else {
    alert("No pudimos obtener acceso a tu ubicación el servicio de clima estara deshabilitado");
  }
});

function savePosition(position) {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    console.log(position.coords.longitude);
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer para mandar esa información a nodeJS para usarla con mi api del clima?

Comment: Podrías usar la [API `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) de JS para realizar las peticiones a tu backend de Node. Otra forma sería usar llamadas [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Primeros_Pasos). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esto desde el cliente en `JavaScript` con `AJAX` para hacer la petición a tu servidor en `Node.js`

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://127.0.0.1", // endpoint de tu servidor
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false, JSON.stringify({
  data: {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  })
}

$.ajax(settings).done(response => {
  // 'response' es tu respuesta del servidor
});
```

Del lado del servidor vas a necesitar hacer una función para recibir el POST.

No conozco la arquitectura con la que trabajas, pero si usas `Node.js` como servidor para tu pagina web como tal y no solo un API, puedes meter los datos en un formulario de `HTML` y mandarlo en un submit a la pagina que lo procesa y te rediriga a la siguiente. Esto si manejas una arquitectura de forms.

Espero haberte ayudado un poco.